# no such file or directory, python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy trabajando python, con la GUI tkinter y tratando de colocar un favicon, y una imagen en un label, dentro de mi app python, pero me marca un error:

couldn't open "imagen.gif": no such file or directory:
tengo el siguiente codigo

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
root.iconbitmap('/favicon.ico') # favicon
img = PhotoImage(file="imagen.gif") # imagen del label
label2 = Label(root, image=img)
label2.pack()
```

en esta linea:

```
 root.iconbitmap('/favicon.ico') # favicon
```

si le agrego el / a favicon.ico, y pongo la imagen
directamente en el disco c: el programa me lo reconoce.y carga el favicon.
pero si solo coloco  ('favicon.ico'), y coloco la imagen en la misma carpeta del archivo. este no me lo reconoce.
me marca que no encuentra el archivo. lo mismo para PhotoImage, si le antepongo a la imagen /,  y coloco la imagen directo en el disco C, este funciona.
pero si le quito el "/" y coloco la imagen en la misma carpeta del archivo, este ya no funciona y me dice que no lo encuentra.
que podria estar haciendo mal?
muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Muy bien descrito el problema, eso es porque debes indicarle a la función iconbitmap el directorio donde estás trabajando. En Python es muy común usar `os.getcwd()` para ese fin.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
root= Tk()
root.iconbitmap('@' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'favicon.ico'))
img = PhotoImage(file="imagen.gif") # imagen del label
label2 = Label(root, image=img)
label2.pack()
```

Comment: Yo siempre pude usar paths relativos sin ningún problema en Tkinter. Sabes por que al op le ocurre ese error?

Comment: Son cuestiones de implementación. Si la respuesta te ha servido, no olvides marcarla como correcta ;)

Comment: Gracias Marcelo, he intentado tu codigo y ahora me marca:
"TclError: error reading bitmap file"
cuando por cmd, me posiciono directamente en la carpeta donde tengo el archivo y despues en visual estudiocode, presiono el boton de RUN PHYTON FILE, ahora si me funciona, pero debo estar posicionado en la consola sobre esa carpeta.
Agradezco mucho la ayuda.
me funciona en el codigo anterior, cuando implemento el tuyo me marca error. sin contar que tampoco me funciona cuando genero el .exe